# Comparing Column to column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I have a column in one table (statename) that looks like this:
TBLOTHER(statename)

- Hidalgo Federal Hwy 130
- Mexico Federal Hwy 130
- Puebla Federal Hwy 130
- Veracruz-Llave Federal Hwy 130

and another column in a different table where there is no Federal Highway numbers, just the state names 
TBLSTATE(name)

- Hidalgo
- Mexico
- Puebla
- Veracruz-Llave

How can I compare the column in tblstate(name) to tblother(name)? I want to copy over the values of a different column in TBLSTATE over to the TBLOTHER based on the name being the same..thanks

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this:

```
where tbl2.name like tbl1.name ||'%'
```

or you could do some fancy substr comparison

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  I would take a different approach

```
where substr(tblother.statename, 1, len(tblstate.name)) = tblstate.name
```

That is, compare the two strings up to the length of the actual state name.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in `TBLOTHER` is as regular as it is here, my guess is that it would be safest to strip off the `Federal Hwy' bit and then compare, i.e.

```
where tblstate.name = substr( tblother.statename, 
                              1, 
                              instr( tblother.statename, 'Federal Hwy' ) - 1 )
```

That's a bit more work than just doing a straight `LIKE` but it helps if you can possibly have names like 'Puebla' and `Puebla-Foo` where one contains the other.

Comment: @aF - But `LIKE` would match `Puebla` in `TBLSTATE` to both `Puebla Federal Hwy 130` and to `Puebla-Foo Federal Hwy 130` in `TBLOTHER`.  Presumably, the desire would be for only `Puebla` to match `Puebla Federal Hwy 130` and only `Puebla-Foo` to match `Puebla-Foo Federal Hwy 130`.

Comment: that I can't presume from the question (not from USA ^^).